# Why are convex operations on negative L2 norm not convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the loss function:
$$
\text{L} = \sum_{u=0}^{M-1}(X_{u}-(10-\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{N - 1} (Z_{u,i} - Y_{i})^2}{N}}))^2
$$

$$\text{where:} \\ Z = \mathbb{R}^{m{\times}n} \text{ matrix}  $$
$$ X = \mathbb{R}^{m{\times}1} \text{ matrix} $$
$$ Y = \mathbb{R}^{1{\times}n} \text{ matrix} $$
$$0<=Z,X,Y<=10$$

This function is strictly convex in terms of X but not convex in Y. Is there a way to make an RMSE function convex in terms of X, Y or both without changing the RMSE aspect of the equation? I feel like it should be convex because: the rmse or l2 norm is convex -> 10 - concave l2 norm is concave -> affine variable minus concave function is convex - > convex squared is convex (above zero) -> sum of convex functions is convex. However the eigen vectors in matlab have negative solutions. Is this equation convex, strictly convex or not convex at all?

[DCP](https://dcp.stanford.edu/analyzer?expr=square(u%20-%20(10%20-%20norm2(x%20-%20y)))) seems to go wrong at squaring but matlab at sqrt.

Hessian values for x1...xm =
[2, 0]
[0, 2]

Cholesky Factorisation for x1...xm =
[2^{1/2},       0]
[      0, 2^{1/2}]

eigen values for x1...xm =
2
2

values from Y and both X and Y matrices from matlab is too complex to meaningfully include here